# Rails: how to iterate over subset of model's fields to create input field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, iteration

I have a model as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :twitter, :dribbble, :forrst,
                  :github, :stackoverflow, :linkedin

  # validations, functions, etc.
end
```

In my view, I would like to iterate over the social accounts (twitter, dribbble, forrst, github, stackoverflow and linkedin) to create text fields for them as follows:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% %w[twitter dribbble forrst github stackoverflow linkedin].each do |account| %>
    <%= account %> username: <%= f.text_field :account %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How do I give the `f.text_field` the right `:account`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= f.text_field account.to_sym %>
```

Answer (score 2):

To keep it DRY, do this:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% User.accessible_attributes.each do |account| %>
    <%= account %> username: <%= f.text_field account.to_sym %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: only if no accessible attributes are added, but generally this is a better idea. Or at least make an array on user and use that for the form and attr_accessible.